# How do I make Udon noodles fat?

Tags: pasta, asian-cuisine, noodles, japanese-cuisine

When I get Udon at a restaurant, they're these massively thick noodles. When I cook them they look like linguine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you making udon noodles from scratch or are you cooking pre-made noodles?

Comment: @nixy: pre-made

Comment: Udon are pretty easy to make from scratch so that you can cut them as thick as you like. (http://www.shesimmers.com/2009/07/how-to-make-chewy-homemade-udon-noodles.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the dried noodles that are marketed as "udon"—at least in my experience in the USA—are actually mislabeled, thinner noodles like [Hiyamugi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiyamugi) or even [Sōmen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C5%8Dmen).  I would suggest buying the semi-dried variety that are usually packaged in vacuum sealed plastic.  This variety is shelf stable, but it can often be found in the refrigerated section of Asian mega-marts.  The noodles will already be almost full size before cooking.

Answer (score 3):

Udon noodles can be anywhere between 4 and 8mm thick. They shouldn't shrink in cooking; if anything, they should expand as they absorb the water. I'd suggest that if you want super-thick noodles, make sure you buy super-thick noodles!